# More than one page in HTML

Tags: html

How do I make nested files that can access other files?

I have a website with the following code to access different pages:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <a href="scenes/home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="scenes/projects.html">projects</a>
</div>
```

Where I have a folder named "scenes" with the HTML code for each page inside the folder.

When I click the link, It brings me to the correct page, but the page isn't able to access CSS or JS.

Here's my folder structure:

```
index.html

js:
    displayProjects.js
    projects.js

scenes:
    home.html
    projects.html

style.css
```

Comment: How are you serving these pages? Locally? Cloud?

Comment: Sounds like there's something wrong with those files in that folder.

Comment: Phix: I use repl.it, a free, online way for me to publish my site. I'm pretty sure the files are served from the cloud. Roddy: If so, how do I change the files so they're not wrong?

Comment: Will you provide the contents of those files in the question? We can't know what's wrong without seeing that. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want this comment to be too large, so here's my website link: https://code-1.theparadox31415.repl.co/

If you do ctrl+u (and command + u on mac, I think), you can see the HTML code.

Both scenes have the following code as seen here: view-source:https://code-1.theparadox31415.repl.co/scenes/projects.html

(Just realized now I should have put it in the question, and that you said to do that as well...)

Comment: Can you show us your folder structure perhaps?

Comment: Okay! I just put that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wanting to see something like the attached screenshot, it looks to me like the path to your CSS file needs to be changed to

```
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Good luck, I hope this helps!

[image]

Update:

> How can I get my javascript to run only on the correct page? As in, my javascript on the updated projects page doesn't run

The path to one of your js scripts should be

```
<script src="../../js/projects.js"></script>
```

the ../../ indicates that the js directory is 2 levels up from the current page. For a little more info on file paths, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp might be helpful.  I couldn't find  the script.js file. Where is it relative to projects.js?

Comment: Okay, it works now!  This is my first time posting a question on stack overflow, and it's been awesome!

Comment: How can I get my javascript to run only on the correct page? As in, my javascript on the updated projects page doesn't run.

Comment: please see my comment above regarding the js scripts @The_Paradox

Comment: There is not script.js file- does there need to be?

Comment: I just realized why you asked- Thanks for your help! I have fixed it now!

Answer (score 2):

> However, when the link is clicked, it brings you to a page with all
> the text that the HTML file says to create- but it doesn't have the
> CSS formatting, nor does it run my javascript.

Probably because the paths to the CSS and Javascripts are relative to the home directory. So for example, `styles/style.css` would have to be changed to `../styles/style.css` to first jump out of the scenes folder.

Comment: [Firefox returns 404](http://prntscr.com/wm6skk), that should confirm it's a problem with the path. Upvote :D

Comment: I don't think I quite understand- how would I change `style.css` to work with the other scenes?

Comment: @The_Paradox, i've changed the code in your page and [it worked](http://prntscr.com/wm6un4)

Comment: @The_Paradox you wouldn't change the contents of the file itself, just the path to it in the head tags. For example, `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/style.css">`

Comment: Yes, I realized that after Gunther posted his comment and David his question. Thanks for your help!